# Texts style do EditText - Underline em ZigZag

Tags: android, android-layout, edittext, android-styles

Eu tenho um edittext que quando ele detecta uma palavra específica ele a destaca por exemplo:

```
print("Destaque")
```

A palavra `print` será destacado.

Só que até ai tudo bem mas eu quero que toda vez que ele detectar uma variável ou uma palavra que esteja errada de acordo a um conjunto de palavras reconhecida pelo meu app (um editor de codigos) ele faça o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Explicação: eu quero que fica mais ou menos esses underline e a cor tanto faz eu que a escolho.

Eu estou fazendo uma espécie de editor de códigos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use um SpannableString e aplique-lhe um ReplacementSpan:

```
public class ZigZagUnderlineSpan extends ReplacementSpan{
    private Paint linePaint;
    private int textMessureWidth;
    private float lineOffsetFromTextBottom = 0;
    private float lineSpaceX = 6;
    private float lineSpaceY = 6;

    public ZigZagUnderlineSpan(){
        linePaint = new Paint();
        linePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        linePaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        textMessureWidth = (int)paint.measureText(text, start, end);
        Paint.FontMetricsInt metrics = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
        if (fm != null) {
            fm.ascent = metrics.ascent;
            fm.descent = metrics.descent;
            fm.top = metrics.top;
            fm.bottom = metrics.bottom;
        }
        return textMessureWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {

        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);

        float lineY = y + lineOffsetFromTextBottom;
        float xLeft = paint.measureText(text, 0, start);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(xLeft, lineY);

        float vertexX = xLeft;
        float vertexY = lineY;
        for(int n = 0; n < textMessureWidth / lineSpaceX; n++){
            path.lineTo(vertexX, vertexY);
            vertexX += lineSpaceX;
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                vertexY = lineY + lineSpaceY;
            }else{
                vertexY = lineY;
            }
        }
        path.lineTo(textMessureWidth, vertexY);
        canvas.drawPath(path, linePaint);
    }
}
```

Use assim:

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Texto errado");
spannableString.setSpan(new ZigZagUnderlineSpan(),0,spannableString.length(),SpannableString.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spannableString);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Isto que você deseja se chama *Spell Check*, estou quase certo que isto deveria ser **ativado por padrão**, no entanto pode *"tentar"*:

```
 editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT);
```

Ainda sim creio que talvez você tenha desabilitado (ou seja padrão) o spellcheck no seu sistema Android (emulador ou celular), então para habilitar tente isto (o caminho pode variar dependendo da versão do Android):

<kbd>Configurar</kbd> > <kbd>Idioma e entrada</kbd> então selecione o checkbox <kbd>Corretor ortográfico</kbd>:

[image: configurar]

---

### Desabilitar spellCheck

Uma **dica extra**, para acaso alguém queira desabilitar é definir no `EditText` isto:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Ou via código:

```
 editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Comment: O que eu quero é que o ```meu app``` que detecte o erro e mude a cor do underline que fica na palavra.

Comment: @AndronCreation você disse: `ou uma palavra que esteja errada`, é exatamente isso que o Spell Check faz. Você chegou a tentar?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ele quer fazer algo como um editor de códigos com "Intellisense".

Comment: @itscorey então a descrição da pergunta esta levando a outro entendimento, isso seria um problema chamado de [**problema XY** já muitos debatido no Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/3635), o autor pergunta Y quando a intenção era perguntar Y, logo eu respondi o que foi perguntado e o problema tem que ser resolvido editando a pergunta e deixando claro a real necessidade. Todavia não dá pra afirmar se é *Intellisense* de fato o que ele deseja, então irei aguardar o AP revisar a pergunta, porque não podemos no basear por hipóteses.

Comment: Eh isso mesmo apesar de que eu não saiba o quê eh intellisnse

Comment: @AndronCreation mas então a intenção não é apontar palavras erradas? Seria qual então

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta.

Comment: @AndronCreation ok, assim que possivel vou editar a resposta, já tenho até a noção de como fazer o que deseja, de qualquer forma recomendo muito que leia isto https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/3635 para evitar futuros problemas assim. Obrigado.

Comment: Demorei um pouco a entender também. Mas percebi que era sobre `Intellisense` ou algo parecido quando ele falou que a palavra `print` deveria ser destacada em algum momento, ou seja, é como se fosse uma `keyword` no EditText dele. Foi difícil entender mesmo.

Comment: @itscorey sim, a pergunta estava com problema de "XY": https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/3635, estou tentando criar um exemplo com um lib nativa e irei editar a resposta

Answer (score -1):

Use regex com replace, como não sei ao certo que tipo de editor usa fiz um exemplo básico que funcina com "$teste" e "var teste":

[Regex de EXEMPLO clique aqui para ver](https://jsfiddle.net/oafd2w9z/1/)

HTML do exemplo:

```
<textarea id="texto" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
<div id="editor" style="width:100%; height:800px;background: #eee;"></div>
```

Js do Exemplo:

```
$("#editor").click(function() {
  $("#texto").focus();
});
$("#texto").keyup(function() {
  var texto = $("#texto").val();
  var sub = texto.replace(/(\$|(var))/g,'<u style="color: red;">$1</u>');
  $("#editor").html(sub);
});
```

Comment: Eu gostaria de fazer mas pelo android

Comment: Eita foi mal kkkk nem me atentei as tags, como desativei as relacionadas a JAVA achei que a dúvida era sobre javascript...

Comment: @Guilherme Bianardi não se preocupe.